# Azure Function fails locally with OutOfMemoryException

Tags: azure-functions

I'm developing an Azure Function v1 that does some calculations with high memory consumption. The problem is that when I debug it locally, it fails with OutOfMemory exception when it consumes ~120 MB. It happens both in VS 2017 and VS 2019.

The same code works perfectly fine in a console app.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to increase this limit and debug the function locally?

Comment: Is it 32 bit or 64 bit ? How long does it take to complete your `calculations` ?

Comment: @HariHaran, it's set as AnuCPU and I execute it on x64 machine. The calculations take up to 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this may be due to the fact you are trying to run a 64 bit library or calculation in functions, which by default the VS tooling pulls down a 32 bit build.  So would make sense you’d see this depending on how memory is being used.  To use 64-bit functions for development you have to manually replace the function runtime executable it’s using with one of the releases (in your case, a function v1 release)

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/117

Another way to test would be deploying your code to the cloud and setting the bitness to 64 bit in function settings.  This would also test in 64 bit and could confirm if that would resolve.